# ROS2 Colcon Option List

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-bouncy, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

is there any place where I can find a detailed list of Colcon options?
I usually go to different websites to find different options.

In particular I'm looking for any option to change the default installation directory.
I'm currently using "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX" cmake option but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308759/ros2-colcon-option-list/) by [gmosem](https://answers.ros.org/users/38572/gmosem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When passing `--help` to the command it will enumerate all available options. The documentation also describes a few use cases: https://colcon.readthedocs.io/

The argument you are trying to pass `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=...` is a CMake option and therefore would need to be passed as `--cmake-args -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=...`. But this specific argument won't work as you would expect it since `colcon` already passes that argument for you (since CMakes default would be to install the package globally into the system which isn't usually desired).

You can choose the install location by passing `--install-base ...` instead. For CMake packages that will effectively set `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=...` and for other package types - e.g. Python packages - will do the equivalent option.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1